# Laravel 8 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For some reason a user cannot delete a Loan request if it has a bid placed on it, it was working before but when I linked loan requst with bidding on them. I have been getting this error, I can't even delete it in phpmyadmin (mysql), unless I delete the bids associated with the loan request.

**Error.**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`holdings`.`bids`, CONSTRAINT `bids_loan_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`loan_id`) REFERENCES `loan_request` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `loan_request` where `id` = 4)

[Image showing sql error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bi71.png)

my Schemas;

**Loan_request**

```
Schema::create('loan_request', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
        $table->integer('LoanType');
        $table->Biginteger('amount');
        $table->string('PayType');
        $table->integer('IntervalPay');
        $table->string('GracePeriod');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('users_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')->ondelete('cascade');
    });
```

my **Bids** schema

```
Schema::create('bids', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('loan_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->decimal('interest');
        $table->string('PayType');
        $table->integer('IntervalPay');
        $table->string('GracePeriod');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')->ondelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('loan_id')
        ->references('id')->on('loan_request')->ondelete('cascade');
    });
```

And the responsible Controller;
**Loancontroller**

```
function delete($id)
{
    Loan_requests::find($id)->delete();
    session()->flash('status','Loan Request deleted successfully');
    return redirect('beg');
}
```

config/database.php

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ]

    
],
```

Comment: Can you show me `config/database.php`

Comment: what specific part of the file shuold i send

Comment: the `connections => [ mysql .... ` part. Add it to the question.

Comment: added the part already

Comment: `'engine' => null,`, change that to `'engine' => 'InnoDB'`, it will stop this from happening on future migrations. And the `onDelete('cascade')` functionality should also work.

Comment: The error you've shown relates to the `holdings` table, which you have not shown the schema for. You are using outdated syntax for your foreign key definition, there has been a [much more concise syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) for years now. And you should name tables and models consistent with Laravel conventions: the table should be the plural of the model name, foreign keys should be the model name and `_id`, and model names should not use snake case. Your `loan_request`, `Loan_request` and `loan_id` does not follow this properly.

Comment: the use this approach gives a warning,  PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant InnoDB - assumed 'InnoDB' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/austin/devops/codebase/holdings/config/database.php on line 60.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first, delete from bid table

```
bids::where('bids.loan_id', $id)->delete();
```

After that

```
Loan_requests::find($id)->delete();
session()->flash('status','Loan Request deleted successfully');
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: tip: use softdelete() for creat table : https://www.laravelcode.com/post/laravel-8-soft-delete-example-tutorial

Comment: it worked, but whats the point of having
`
$table->foreign('loan_id')
            ->references('id')->on('loan_request')->ondelete('cascade');
`
the ondelete('cascade') if i still have to delete it first via the controller

Comment: must use ( UNSIGNED ) at attribute in MySQL

Comment: This just works around the problem, and does not properly solve it.